# I can not see my parameter which is annotated @RequestBody in Swagger-ui

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui

I can not see possibility to add needed parameter into my micro-service in POST request. This is my code:

```
@Operation(summary = "Send a mail. It is possible to add to the mail a carbon copy and attachments.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Mail sent successfully "),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Something went wrong while sending the email.", content = @Content)
    })
    @PostMapping("/send")
    public void sendMailWithTemplate(@RequestBody Form form) {
        emailService.sendMail(form.getTo(), form.getCc(), form.getSubject(), form.getText(), form.getFile());
    }
```

and this is a dependency part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-parser-v3</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0-M1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I am adding a view of my swagger-ui

Could you please help me? Thank you.

I tried googling the answer and also chatting with chat.gpt

Comment: I thought springfox and swagger are incompatible. Did I miss something?

Comment: What kind of parameter you need to add?
Could you please explain more?

Comment: I created a class Form where are all my needed parameters I have been told to do it via REST and not via URL is there another way? If I need to add anything more I will likely provide more information

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***
I found a way how to do it.

Import of annotation @RequestBody should be:
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

at least it is how it works for me